# C++ cannot catch the exception thrown from curlpp in Mac OS with g++-mp-4.4

Tags: c++, exception

I have following code (now compilable, thanks to @LokiAstari):

To compile the following piece of code, the simplest way is to download [curlpp](https://bitbucket.org/jpbarrette/curlpp/) , compile it. Then compile the following code with g++-mp-4.4 (installed by macport), linking to curl and curlpp.

It would crash (output: `abort trap`) if localhost:8080 does not exist.
Change g++-mp-4.4 to g++ which the default one of Xcode 4, it works fine.

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

#include <curlpp/cURLpp.hpp>
#include <curlpp/Easy.hpp>
#include <curlpp/Options.hpp>

int main(int, char **)
{
    try
    {
        curlpp::Cleanup myCleanup;

        {
          std::ostringstream os;
          os << curlpp::options::Url("http://localhost:8080/");
        }

    }
    catch( curlpp::RuntimeError &e )
    {
        std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
    }

    catch( curlpp::LogicError &e )
    {
        std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
    }

  return 0;
}
```

Update:

in Easy.cpp:

```
void 
curlpp::Easy::perform()
{
    mCurl->perform(); // The exception come from here. mCurl is a std::auto_ptr<internal::CurlHandle> mCurl;
}

......

std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & stream, const curlpp::Easy & request)
{
  // Quick clone that doesn't copy options, only the curl handle.
  curlpp::Easy r(request.getCurlHandle().clone());
  r.setOpt(new curlpp::options::WriteStream(& stream));
  r.perform(); // The exception come from here.

  return stream;
}
```

in CurlHandle.cpp:

```
void CurlHandle::perform()
{
    CURLcode code;

    code = curl_easy_perform(mCurl);
    throwException();
    libcurlRuntimeAssert(mErrorBuffer, code); //if we got an error
}
```

in Exception.cpp:

```
void curlpp::libcurlRuntimeAssert(const std::string & reason, CURLcode code)
{
  curlpp::libcurlRuntimeAssert(reason.c_str(), code);
}

void curlpp::libcurlRuntimeAssert(const char * reason, CURLcode code)
{
  if (code != CURLE_OK)
    throw curlpp::LibcurlRuntimeError(reason, code);
}
```

I traced into the code, `throw curlpp::LibcurlRuntimeError(reason, code);`, the constructor of `LibcurlRuntimeError` is fine, then throw, then SIGABRT.

stack trace:

```
0   __kill      0   0x7fff8213d0b6  
1   abort       0   0x7fff821dd9f6  
2   uw_init_context_1       0   0x101663af2 
3   _Unwind_Resume      0   0x101663f38 
4   operator<<  Easy.cpp    118 0x10009b699 
5   operator<<  Options.cpp 34  0x1000948d8 
6   RoleCreationTest::loadPlayerAsyncTestCase   rolecreationtest.cpp    147 0x10008c714 
7   RoleCreationTest::qt_metacall   moc_rolecreationtest.cpp    87  0x1000acab2 
8   QMetaMethod::invoke     0   0x1012e6667
```

Comment: Why not catch the exception by *constant* reference? Also, what happens if you add a catch-all block?

Comment: I'm thinking that `os << url` doesn't do that you think it does, i.e. it doesn't throw the exception. Try to step in the code with a debugger.

Comment: My guess is that somewhere in your call stack there's a function that's defined either as `nothrow` or with a throw specification that doesn't contain the exception you mention. Though, @AndreaBergia is more likely correct than me.

Comment: Check if the correct exception is being thrown or not ? There is maybe another exception lurking behind the shadows.

Comment: Show us `url` `operator<<( )` method

Comment: Add `catch (...)` to test Andrea's theory.

Comment: @KerrekSB, the catch(...) does not work. I have added the stack trace.

Comment: @AJG85 I tried, it does not work.

Comment: @AndreaBergia Yes, I have just run the debugger, step by step, and it is fine until `throw ....` in Exception.cpp.

Comment: @Omnifarious Following your suggestion, I did a global search, no `nothrow` or any `throw` appears after function definition.

Comment: Give us a compilable piece of code that we can compile and run that reproduces the problem. Don;t post your whole program reduce the program to the smallest possible bit o code that reproduces the error. In doing this you may just find the error yourself.

Comment: @LokiAstari Thanks, I have updated it.

Comment: `catch(...)` does work. You either introduced a new bug, the exception isn't being thrown, or it's being handled elsewhere poorly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are problems with various MacPorts GCC 4.x compilers and exception catching, see for example [GCC bug 42159](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=42159) and [MacPorts bug 25042](https://trac.macports.org/ticket/25042).

Comment: Thank you. That is it, the ABI problem.